# How to change scrollbar color in pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I Tried the below code, the color is not reflected, Am I missing something?

```
#add description box beside test cases
        testCaseDescWindow = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        testCaseDescWindow.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        testCaseDescWindow.get_vscrollbar().modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,gtk.gdk.color_parse('#40515F'))
        testCaseDescWindow.get_hscrollbar().modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,gtk.gdk.color_parse('#40515F'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the foreground color which `GtkScrollbar` probably does not use.

You could try to use `GtkCssProvider` and check which property is the correct to modify (see  http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-2-the-gtk-css-and-gtk-widgets-css-files/ for list of properties)